# Is this a covariance bug in C# 4?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

In the following piece of code I expected to be able to implicitly cast from `elements` to `baseElements` because `TBase` is implicitly convertible to `IBase`.

```
public interface IBase { }
public interface IDerived : IBase { }
public class VarianceBug
{
    public void Foo<TBase>() where TBase : IBase
    {
        IEnumerable<TBase> elements = null;
        IEnumerable<IDerived> derivedElements = null;
        IEnumerable<IBase> baseElements;

        // works fine
        baseElements = derivedElements;

        // error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 
        //   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TBase>' to 
        //   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IBase>'. 
        //   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
        baseElements = elements;
    }
}
```

However, I get the error that is mentioned in the comment.

Quoting from the spec:

> A type `T<A1, …, An>` is variance-convertible to a type `T<B1, …, Bn>` if `T` is either an interface or a delegate type declared with the variant type parameters `T<X1, …, Xn>`, and for each variant type parameter `Xi` one of the following holds:
>
> - `Xi` is covariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from `Ai` to `Bi`
> - `Xi` is contravariant and an implicit reference or identity conversion exists from `Bi` to `Ai`
> - `Xi` is invariant and an identity conversion exists from `Ai` to `Bi`

Checking my code, it appears to be consistent with the spec:

- `IEnumerable<out T>` is an interface type
- `IEnumerable<out T>` is declared with variant type parameters
- `T` is covariant
- an implicit reference conversion exists from `TBase` to `IBase`

So - is it a bug in the C# 4 compiler?

Comment: What happens when you do cast explicitly? The compiler says that there is one. Since you are downcasting it kinda makes sense..?

Comment: Just to make it explicit - it is your last bullet "an implicit reference conversion exists from TBase to IBase" that is untrue (unless you add `: class`). It may be assignable, but it is *not* necessarily a reference-conversion. Without the `: class` it is a "constrained" conversion, which is some magic that lets the same IL call methods (including property accessors) on reference-types and value-types in the same way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx

Comment: Charles: you're wrong - the first assignment works (Works on My Machine (TM)).

Comment: Mark: right - my bad. It is not a reference type, so there's no reference conversion. However I'm left with the question of why does the first assignment works?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Variance only works for reference-types (or there is an *identity* conversion). It is not known that `TBase` is reference type, unless you add `: class`:

```
 public void Foo<TBase>() where TBase : class, IBase
```

since I could write a:

```
public struct Evil : IBase {}
```

Comment: Good answer - adding class constraint works.
However - this raises another question: why does the first assignment works?

Comment: @Omer - because `IBase` and `IDerived` *are* treated as references; it is only `TBase` that is undecided.

Comment: @MarcGravell: To be more precise, while interfaces may be implemented by non-heap (value) types, a storage location of an interface type will *always* hold a heap object reference. For example, a `List<IEnumerator<int>>` holds references to heap objects implementing `IEnumerator<int>`, while a `List<T> where T:IEnumerator<int>` would, if `T` is `List<int>.Enumerator`, holds instances of that struct type instead. Note that if one tried to store a `List<int>.Enumerator` in a `List<IEnumerator<int>>`, the system would copy its fields to a new heap object and store a reference to that.

Comment: In other situations that's exactly the great thing about generics: That if a type parameter `T` is a value type, then we do not get boxing. For example if `T` happens to be `Int32`, a `List<T>` is not a list of boxed integers. However with interfaces we have boxing, for example `var li = new List<IFormattable> { 2, 4, 6, };` gives a list of boxes.

Answer (score 14):

Marc is correct - I was just about to paste the same response.

See the Covariance & Contravariance FAQ:

http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

From the FAQ:

"Variance is supported only if a type parameter is a reference type."

**Variance is not supported for value types**

The following doesn’t compile either:

```
// int is a value type, so the code doesn't compile.
IEnumerable<Object> objects = new List<int>(); // Compiler error here.
```

Comment: And more in line with the question, the following won't work either: `IEnumerable<IComparable> comparables = new List<int>();`