# Covariance, delegates and generic type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, covariance

```
public void Foo<T>(Func<T> bar)
 where T: IMyInterface
{
   Func<IMyInterface> func = bar;
}
```

***It has been a while since I'd understood covariance, but shouldn't this compile?***

Anything `bar` can return is also an `IMyInterface`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: That's the automatic "this is a duplicate" comment the system adds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Is this a covariance bug in C# 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783233/is-this-a-covariance-bug-in-c-sharp-4)

the correct code is:

```
public void Foo<T>(Func<T> bar)
 where T: class, IMyInterface
{
   Func<IMyInterface> func = bar;
}
```