# Why covariance does not work with generic method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance, contravariance

Assume I have interface and class:

```
public interface ITree {}
public class Tree : ITree {}
```

As `IEnumerable<T>` is *covariant*, the code line below is compiled successfully:

```
IEnumerable<ITree> trees = new List<Tree>();
```

But when I put it into generic method:

```
public void Do<T>() where T : ITree
{
     IEnumerable<ITree> trees = new List<T>();
}
```

I get compiled error from compiler:

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\lab\Lab.General\Lab.General\Program.cs   83  40  Lab.General

Why covariance does not work in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a covariance bug in C# 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783233/is-this-a-covariance-bug-in-c-sharp-4)

Comment: Why not just cast `design`: `list.Add((IDesign<IVehicle>)design);`?

Comment: One of the things I find interesting about the ste is that everyone insists on a [mre], but when a poster comes up with a nice minimalist example, someone says "well, you could just..."

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That is because variance only works with reference types (classes, interfaces & delegates). Add a class constraint and it compiles just fine:

```
public static void Do<T>() where T : class, ITree
```

Comment: Thank, I mislead that when doing constraint `T : ITree` it is implicit that T is reference type, but it actually is not

Comment: If `ITree` is an interface type, a storage location of type `ITree` will always hold either `null` or a reference to a heap object that implements `ITree`, but a storage location of a generic type constrained to `ITree` may hold a reference or it may hold an actual instance of a value type which implements `ITree`.  Personally, I dislike the way that structs which implement interfaces are implicitly converted to heap references which implement those interfaces without the structs having any say in the matter.  Value-type semantics differ from rerefence semantics in USEFUL ways, but...

Comment: ...the "unified type system" model assumes (wrongly) that they will behave identically.  A variable of type `List<string>.Enumerator` implements `IEnumerable<string>`, but holds something whose behavior is very different from that of a variable of type `IEnumerable<string>` which holds a reference to a `List<string>.Enumerator`.

Comment: @supercat I guess you mean `IEnumerator<string>`, not `IEnumerable`. It is true that value types get boxed when you store them in a variable of interface type. The **good** thing about generics is that we don't get boxing there. So if you say `Do<MyStruct>()` where `MyStruct` is a struct implementing the interface, then you get a specific "version" of the method for `MyStruct`. So if inside the method it says `T localT = default(T);` then the code produces a value of `MyStruct` and makes **no** boxing which is cool. But with `ITree localT = default(T);` of course you get a boxed value.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: You are correct. The problem is that a struct which implements a mutating interface will have struct semantics, but if cast to that interface it will become (and behave as) a reference type with a broken `Equals` method. While it's useful to have a concept of interfaces that can be implemented by value types, I'm not sure it's useful to say that a boxed structure implicitly implements the interfaces of the original; it might be more useful to allow structures to define casts to interfaces (where the cast would yield a new object which does implement the interface).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Actually, another thing that would have helped ease the confusion would have been to have the `For Each` and `foreach` in vb.net and C# check for the existence of a `GetDuckTypedEnumerator()` method before `GetEnumerator`, using the former if it exists.  That would allow a class to have `GetEnumerator` return a *class-type* `IEnumerator<T>` and have `GetDuckTypeEnumerator` return a struct which does not implement `IEnumerator<T>`.  If boxed types are going to have `Equals` report value equality (it can't report reference equality), they should be immutable.  That would be...

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: ...a problem if one wanted to have a struct implement `IEnumerator<T>`, but not a problem if one wanted to have a struct which was only used with duck-typed `ForEach`.

Comment: @supercat I studied `List<>.GetEnumerator()` a bit. It always returns a **mutable value-type**. If you call the "direct" instance method and assign to a `var` typed variable, you get no boxing, because the formal return type is the type of the struct (`List<>.Enumerator`). If you call the explicit interface implementations, of course your formal return type is a reference type (`IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<>`), but you still gets the same struct value, only **boxed** of course. After that you have all the "unusual" features of mutable structs (calling `MoveNext()` mutates the value).

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add more examples:
You can call `MakeDesignWhereTIsReference` and pass `VehicleStruct` as `T`. But the problem is that:

> Covariance and contravariance are supported for reference types, but they are not supported for value types. From [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

So we also need to limit `T` to be a reference type; It may be done with the help of the `class` keyword that adds a restriction we need.

```
public static class TestCovariance
{
    public static void MakeDesignWhereTIsReference<T>()
        where T : class, IVehicle // pay attention to class restriction
    {
        ICollection<IDesign<IVehicle>> list = new List<IDesign<IVehicle>>();
        var design = new Design<T>();
        list.Add(design);
    }

    public static void MakeDesignWhereTIsStruct<T>()
        where T : struct, IVehicle //This method will throw a cast exception
    {
        ICollection<IDesign<IVehicle>> list = new List<IDesign<IVehicle>>();
        var design = new Design<T>();
        list.Add((IDesign<IVehicle>)design);
    }
} 

public struct VehicleStruct : IVehicle { }

TestCovariance.MakeDesignWhereTIsReference<Ship>();
TestCovariance.MakeDesignWhereTIsStruct<VehicleStruct>();
```