# List Generic GetEnumerator Cast To An Interface Fails

Tags: c#, .net, interface, enumerator

GetEnumerator cast to an Interface fails
No compiler error
Runtime failure with message index infinity
If I use the struct Word1252 directly with no interface it works

```
namespace WordEnumerable
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WordEnum wordEnum = new WordEnum();
            Debug.WriteLine(wordEnum[0].GetType().ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(wordEnum[0].Value);
            Debug.WriteLine(wordEnum.Count.ToString());
            foreach (iWord w in wordEnum)  // fails here
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
public interface iWord
{
    Int32 Key { get; }
    String Value { get; }
}
public class WordEnum : IEnumerable<iWord>
{
    private static List<Word1252> words1252 = new List<Word1252>();
    IEnumerator<iWord> IEnumerable<iWord>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<iWord>)words1252).GetEnumerator();
    }
    public struct Word1252 : iWord
    {
        public UInt64 packed;
        public Int32 Key   { get { return (Int32)((packed >> 27) & ((1 << 25) - 1)); } }
        public Byte Length { get { return (Byte) ((packed >> 59) & ((1 <<  5) - 1)); } }
        public String Value { get { return Key.ToString(); } }
        public Word1252(UInt64 Packed) { packed = Packed; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short that's `upcasting` from `IEnumerable<Word1252>` to `IEnumerable<IWord>`,

And that requires `covariance` to work.

> Even though IEnumerable is marked as `out` (covariant)
>   **Covariance doesn't work for 'value types'** - i.e. the struct you have the
>   interface defined.

e.g. see...

[Is this a covariance bug in C# 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783233/is-this-a-covariance-bug-in-c-sharp-4/2783401#2783401)
(or a bit different but boils down to the same issue)
[Why cannot IEnumerable<struct> be cast as IEnumerable<object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688268/why-cannot-ienumerablestruct-be-cast-as-ienumerableobject/9688362#9688362)

To resolve you can just define your list like

```
private static List<iWord> words1252 = new List<iWord>();
```

Or define your enumerator like this:

```
IEnumerator<iWord> IEnumerable<iWord>.GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (var word in words1252)
        yield return word;
}
```

Comment: They both worked thanks.  With the private static List<iWord> words1252 = new List<iWord>(); I had to cast to Word1252 for internal stuff but I will take that.   Do you know if foreach has a performance penalty?  If not I would rather use that.

Comment: you're welcome. `foreach` is nicer I agree. There is none performance impact there (or some op extra at most) - it's 'yielding' as it goes - so it's basically doing the same as the original 'enumerator' - that's a known and accepted method of 'casting' within `Enumerators' (i.e. when you need to return different item - but are unable to cast)