# Conversion error with generic covariance

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, covariance

I got the following code and it gives me compile error:

```
cannot convert from 'UserQuery.SomeClass<int>' to UserQuery.Interface<System.IConvertible>'
```

the code:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Interface<IConvertible>> values = new List<Interface<IConvertible>>();
    values.Add(new SomeClass<int>() {Value = 50 });
}

interface Interface<out T> where T : IConvertible
{
   T Value { get; }
}
class SomeClass<T> : Interface<T> where T : IConvertible
{
   public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, trying to add `SomeClass<string>` works fine.

```
values.Add(new SomeClass<string>() {Value = "50" });
```

Could anyone please explain me why I can do it for string, but not for int nor double and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer here:
[Is this a covariance bug in C# 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783233/is-this-a-covariance-bug-in-c-sharp-4?rq=1)

Generally, **variance is not supported for value types**. That's why it won't work for int, but does work for string.